# How to display decrypted image via cryptoJS?

Tags: javascript

I want to encrypt images (and indeed any files) using Javascript. I used the cryptojs library. The encryption is sort of successful (although to be honest, I don't even know if the encryption is successful), then I try to decrypt the image and display the blob, but the image is not displayed.

Here is my code:

```js
const imageInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');
    const encryptedTextDiv = document.getElementById('encryptedText');
    const decryptionKeyInput = document.getElementById('decryptionKey');
    const decryptButton = document.getElementById('decryptButton');
    const decryptedImageDiv = document.getElementById('decryptedImage');

    imageInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
      const key = "123456";

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        const encryptedImage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(event.target.result, key);
        encryptedTextDiv.textContent = encryptedImage.toString();
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
    });

    decryptButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const decryptionKey = decryptionKeyInput.value;
      const encryptedImage = encryptedTextDiv.textContent;

      const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedImage, decryptionKey);
      const decryptedImageBlob = new Blob([decryptedBytes], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

      const decryptedImageURL = URL.createObjectURL(decryptedImageBlob);
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = decryptedImageURL;

      decryptedImageDiv.innerHTML = '';
      decryptedImageDiv.appendChild(img);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.js"></script>
  <input type="file" id="imageInput">
  <div id="encryptedText"></div>
  <input type="text" id="decryptionKey" value="123456">
  <button id="decryptButton">Decrypt</button>
  <div id="decryptedImage"></div>
```

*codepen io accountnujen/pen/xxQvQma* just in case

Can you please tell me where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why are you still using cryptoJS ? Your browser can [do AES operations natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) a hundred times faster.